# Expected org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedDependencyResult but found org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultUnresolvedDependencyResult

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build gradle for an app, but its showing me this error.

```
Expected org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedDependencyResult but found org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.result.DefaultUnresolvedDependencyResult
```

I am using **Android studio 3.4**, and **Gradle 5.1.1**

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have some issue. I blieve has to do with some conflict in grandle, in particul with some local dependency and global.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Native, you have probably changed the package name or a default constant. Make sure your package name is same and valid across all files and then run the following commands and it may solve your problem.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

if you are still seeing the same problem try updating `Android Studio` and then invalidate cache by `File>invalidate caches/restart`